# My web app non-deterministically crashes in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototype, webkit, crash

In my web app, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> to navigate from cell to cell in a table.

All cells contain a visible `<span>`, and a hidden `<input>` element -- their values are kept in sync.

When a cell is activated, the `<span>` is hidden, while the input is shown.

Everything works just fine in Firefox, IE, Opera, etc. Yet, when I load up Chrome, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> crashes the page (I'm seeing the "Aw Snap" page). Odd thing is, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> work.

I've identified that the following code is (directly or indirectly responsible for the crashes):

```
/**
 * Deactivates a cell, hiding its input field, and showing its span field
 */
View.prototype.deactivateCell = function (cell){
 //Show the span, hide the input
 var label = cell.descendants()[0];
 var input = cell.descendants()[1];
 if(label){
  label.show();
 }
 if(input){
  //THIS NEXT LINE IN PARTICULAR CAUSES THE CRASH
  //I've also tried input.style.display = "none"; - same result
  input.hide();
 }
}
```

Odd thing is, this code is called by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>, as well as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> - yet it only crashes on <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> -- even with identical `cell` values!

All of these cells have two, and only two, descendants... And the crash has nothing to do with the source cells, or the destination cells -- it's possible to move into any cell from above, but not from the left.

What's even stranger; adding an `alert(1);` at the end of the `deactivateCell(cell)` method prevents the crash. Putting it at the start of the method has no effect (Other then displaying the alert dialogue, before the crash)

I've tried isolating the relevant HTML + this method in a test file - I could not reproduce the crash.

Has anyone encountered this? Should I write it off as a browser bug? Does anyone know how I might debug this, or try to fix it? I haven't the foggiest impression how my Javascript can cause the browser to caput, when so many other websites are fine.

Comment: Can you confirm this on another machine?

Comment: Yes - both my desktop and my laptop. Both versions of Chrome should be up-to-date - it updates itself in the background, no?

Comment: @Vladislav can you dump `input` to the console? Is it always guaranteed to really be a input field? Is there some concurrent updating of the HTML going on that relates to the input element?

Comment: It's an input element - there shouldn't be asynchronous updates happening... When I step through the code with a debugger, everything works fine.

Comment: Vladislav, if you could get a reduction case of that that is reproducible, please file a bug in http://crbug.com/new let me know of the issue# and I will triage it and assign it to people who are familiar with that section.

Comment: I've filed the bug yesterday, and looks like a contributor beat me to providing a reduction. This is a Webkit issue. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58741 Motioning to close the question.

Comment: Instead of closing the question the comment you just posted should be posted as an answer and accepted.

Comment: Deleting the question quite defeats the purpose of this site.

Comment: Please, **do not** delete this question - it's important that you leave your question out for others to find, in case they face similar problems in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a [bug with Webkit](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58741) that was already filed and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a prototype hero, but I noticed that you call `cell.descendants()` without checking if cell is null or not.

Also, are you hiding the current input the cursor is in? if so, try to `focus()` to a different input before you hide the current one.

Comment: `cell` is tested to be not null in the calling method, but thanks - that is a good practice. I've also tried shifting focus - to no avail.